# How can I get products by categoryId from Firebase Realtime Database in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, rest, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get and show categorical products from Firebase Realtime Database in Flutter. There are specific categoryIds where placed in the producst.json for each product. For that, I wrote a query like this.
But I couldn't get products. How should I write this?

Thank You.

```
static Future getProductsByCategoryId(int categoryId){
   return http.get("https://--projectlink--.firebaseio.com/myapp/products.jsoncategoryId=$categoryId");
}
```

Comment: "I couldn't get products" Why not? What is the problem with the code you shared?

Comment: http.get("https://--projectlink--.firebaseio.com/myapp/products.json"); when i call this query the products shows up but when i call it with categoryId I can't get any.

Comment: It gives all products instead of specific ones with categoryId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're constructing the URL wrong. For the Firebase REST API, the `.json` suffix must be at the end of the URL.

So:

```
http.get("https://--projectlink--.firebaseio.com/myapp/products.json?orderBy=\"categoryId\"&equalTo=\"$categoryId\"");
```

Comment: E/flutter ( 4509): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at line 2, character 1)
E/flutter ( 4509): <!DOCTYPE html>

Sorry but not working

Comment: Yeah, I now realize you're trying to do a query, which looks quite different from what you had. I updated in my answer, but mostly this is just string manipulation until you match the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#filtering-by-a-specified-child-key

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer but it didn't work again. I tried json-server there was no problem in there . However, the firebase not working with the same query.

Comment: Here's a working URL against data in a test database: `https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/67244097.json?orderBy="categoryId"&equalTo="a"` Check if your code generates the same URL.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I solved it. It was giving error cause of not adding indexOn attributes to flutter database rules.